# How do I make an "ancient" style design

Tags: website-design, background, texture

I am trying to design a site with a "ancient" feel to it, such as this example:

- [image]

How can I make textures, buttons and background like on those sites?

Comment: Welcome to the site. For people to be able to give you a useful answer, you need to ask one clear question per question. There's a lot going on in that page. If you focus on one element or style at a time, and say what about it you want to learn how to do, people will be able to help. And it's not clear what you mean by "suck textures...", normally suck is a bad thing...

Comment: I think the user meant "such textures", either way NickC made a great edit to the post that clarifies it quite a bit.

Comment: You want us to explain you a complete site design? Haha

Comment: Photoshop. Broad questions get broad answers, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

this is not with just 1 texture the guy merge 2 to 3 different texture and make this... like Curtain texture, Rocks texture, glowing effect and much more this is not possible in one tutorial i think you should learn [psd.tutsplus.com](http://psd.tutsplus.com) this will help you lot to create like this background.